# Redirect htaccess does not work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm new into htaccess and its not redirecting those links!

Any help would apreciate!
Than

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 http://www.mmaemvendas.com/category/entrevistas    http://www.mmaemvendas.com/entrevistas
Redirect 301 http://www.mmaemvendas.com/category/blog   http://www.mmaemvendas.com/blog
Redirect 301 http://www.mmaemvendas.com/category/artigos    http://www.mmaemvendas.com/artigos
Redirect 301 http://www.mmaemvendas.com/category/logistica  http://www.mmaemvendas.com/logistica
Redirect 301 http://www.mmaemvendas.com/category/negociacao http://www.mmaemvendas.com/negociacao
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)optimizemember_file_download\=.+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
```

Comment: What URL is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Redirect a page in Wordpress from htaccess, you can add redirect code at the end of htaccess file. Your default htaccess file will now look alike below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /category/entrevistas http://www.mmaemvendas.com/entrevistas    
Redirect 301 /category/blog http://www.mmaemvendas.com/blog    
Redirect 301 /category/artigos http://www.mmaemvendas.com/artigos    
Redirect 301 /category/logistica  http://www.mmaemvendas.com/logistica    
Redirect 301 /category/negociacao http://www.mmaemvendas.com/negociacao
```

Answer (score -1):

Mahmod!
If you are using WordPress CMS, so you can download & install any free Plugin for 301 Redirects. You can do it in admin panel, at the menu "plugins". Here you will find a search. Enter keywords like "301 redirect plugin" & customize it.
If you wish, we hve [attractive wordpress support services.](https://fruitfulcode.com/get-free-quote/)
Good luck & be happy! ;)